# Does using mysql's api belong to Embedded database?

Tags: mysql, embedded-database

I am confused about "Does using mysql's api belong to Embedded database?",cuz I think using mysql's api only belongs to "Remote connection to the database".For example,I use mysql's api in python code below, does it belong to using embedded database?

```
import pymysql
import random
import time
connect = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='******', db='***')
cursor = connect.cursor()
...
```

At the same time, I want know the difference between "embedded sql and embedded database",Is embedded sql a example of "embedded database"?
Thank you for your assistance in advance!

Comment: What's "dose"? Is that a typo and should read "does"? Otherwise it would be helpful to know what it is. You might want to explain.

Comment: I am sorry to make you confused，it is “does”.

Comment: mysql api is to connect to a mysql database, which is not an embedded database.

Comment: embedded sql is usually C or C++ code that is run through a pre-processor to convert to native calls

Comment: I got it. Many thanks for your kind and warm help.

Comment: embedded mysql exists, but I believe it is not free

Answer (score 1):

[embedded mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/libmysqld.html) is a library that is linked to the application. Everything from the creation of the database and all the data manipulation is contained within the application (hence embedded). Its C/C++ interface contains 4 extra library calls on top of what is normally in the C/C++ interface for talking to a detached/standard/remote database server (aka the mysqld process though a IPC mechanism).

The PyMySQL however is a pure python network only and cannot be embedded. https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient *might* be able to link to the embedded library (that [MariaDB still makes available](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/embedded-mariadb-interface/)) and run as an embedded server if there was a requirement to do so in python.

Comment: I understand. Thanks a million.